# curl, не могу получить контент

Tags: curl, парсер

Хочу получить контент с этого сайта e-rail.progresstour.ru.

Обычной формой делаю POST (3 переменных $from, $to, $fullDate) на адрес e-rail.progresstour.ru/start.aspx выдается расписание, вот оно мне и надо.

Хочу забрать его Curl`ом, делаю так:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://e-rail.progresstour.ru/Start.aspx');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
        'from='.$from.
        '&to='.$to.
        '&FullDate='.$date
        );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera 10.00');
$res = curl_exec($curl);
```

Но в переменную $res получаю не страницу с расписанием, а главную страницу сайта.
В чем может быть проблема?

**Добавлено.**

Добавил полный заголовок, но не дает нужной информации.

```
$headers[] = 'Host: e-rail.progresstour.ru';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
$headers[] = 'Connection:   keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';
$headers[] = 'X-MicrosoftAjax:  Delta=true';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control:    no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
$headers[] = 'Referer:  http://e-rail.progresstour.ru/';
```

Народ, помогите справиться с этим делом!

**Добавлено.**

Всем спасибо, проблему решил, в опциях курла не хватало одной установки "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');" и все заработало, вот весь список опций:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://e-rail.progresstour.ru');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://progresstour.ru');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вы могли заметить, сайт редиректит вас на другую страницу через заголовок `Location /Start.aspx?id=аццкое_число`. `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` может не отрабатывать по нескольким причинам, в частности если "open_basedir or safe_mode are enabled". В коментах к [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) есть несколько вариантов, как это обойти. В простейшем случае, как мне кажется, здесь можно просто вытащить заголовок `Location` из ответа и курлом вытащить данные уже из него.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже ваш запрос отлавливается на там сайте и делает редирект на главную.
Можно попробовать использовать анонмные прокси, но тогда запрос будет выполняться дольше и не факт что выполнится, значит нужно предусмотреть цикл и выбор разных проксей

Тут curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera 10.00'); укажите правильное значение, что-то вроде Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.51, сам использовал так:

```
 $headers = array();
 $headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3';
 $headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
 $headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
 $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip';
 $headers[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Если не помогает, попробуйте отправить запрос на себя же и посмотреть какие данные приходят.

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.